# Clouflare Page Rules - Wildcards not working

Tags: caching, woocommerce, wildcard, cloudflare, cache-control

Im having trouble setting up Cloudflare with woocommerce, the problem being my rules aren't matching when I need them to.

I believe this is down to the wildcards in the rules im trying to use?

I have these rules;

```
1. domain.co.uk/cat/houses/*   >   Cache - Standard
2. domain.co.uk/*              >   Cache - Everything
```

The problem is that `domain.co.uk/cat` still gets missed by the cache even though it should be picked up by rule two. Or am I misunderstanding the way these rules work?

Thanks for reading )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the second rule turn on (origin cache control)

Comment: I don't understand how will this help?